# How to use the /testfor command on a specific player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I have this map that me and my brother Zeal Etage (Minecraft name) play together using LAN. I created a command block system using the `/testfor` command for a money system that rewards on mob-killing. I have a command like this:

```
/testfor [name=ZealEtage,score_skeleton_min=1]
```

but it says the UUID doesn't match. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `testfor`?  There are a few good reasons to use `testfor`, but without seeing more of your command blocks,  I can't say for sure that this is such a case.  If you're only using `testfor` for demonstration purposes, then you'd probably be better served but using the actual command from your contraption.

Comment: I don't get what you're saying well, if you can then show me a way to make a money system. if it is ok. Ths anyway

Comment: So am I correct in assuming that your contraption uses `testfor`?  What I'm saying is that `testfor` generally isn't as useful as people think it is, especially in 1.8 and earlier.  There's usually better ways of doing things that don't use the `testfor` command.  You have at least a basic knowledge of scoreboards, and you're already using it in a selector, which makes me wonder why the `testfor` hasn't already been made redundant.

Comment: well, i just follow this command thing on youtube, i quite understand it but do you mean that there are other ways to build a money system?
P/S: ths for your help

Comment: There are often many ways to build command block contraptions, some better than others. I've found that using `testfor` often leads to designs that are less than optimal, which is why I recommend avoiding it, especially by beginners.  It's one of the easiest commands to misuse because it's a very simple command, but that simplicity makes it very inflexible.  In this specific case, you can probably very easily do away with this instance of `testfor`, unless it's triggering a redstone device.  If you're using it to control other command blocks, the scoreboard is probably the better option.

Comment: that's what i did with my contraption. Ths for your advise, and i think it's alright now.

Answer (score 1):

You need a selector (`@r`, `@a`, `@p`, `@e`) before the selector arguments. Try this:

```
/testfor @a[name=ZealEtage,score_skeleton_min=1]
```

Comment: ths dude! i'll try it

Comment: it worked just fine now! ths so much.